# Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3P motherboard won't start without second RAM module

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I have following config:

- Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3P motherboard
- Intel Core i7-3770 CPU
- Kingston 2x8GB RAM (KHX1600C10D3B1K2/16G)
- Crucial M500 256 GB SSD

RAM modules are inserted in 1st (called DDR3_1) and 3rd (called DDR3_2) RAM slots on motherboard. Computer boots properly with this config.

The problem I have encountered is when I remove one (any) RAM module, motherboard is not starting - it reboot every (approximately) 0.7 seconds.

- I have checked both modules on other machine - they are working properly.
- I have placed by one every module in every slot - it doesn't work.
- I have placed both modules to DDR3_1 and DDR3_3 slots - it doesn't work either.
- I have cleared CMOS - it didn't help.

The only configuration when motherboard boots is when both modules are in DDR3_1 and DDR3_2 slots.

What is going on, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "fix" for the situation that you are describing.

[Your motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.us/microsite/308/images/models.html) is stated by the manufacturer to use dual-channel DDR3 RAM.

[Dual-channel RAM requires two or more memory modules.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Dual-channel_architecture) In a sense, that's where the "dual" part comes from. Borrowing from Wikipedia:

> Dual-channel architecture requires a dual-channel-capable motherboard and two or more DDR, DDR2 SDRAM, or DDR3 SDRAM memory modules. The memory modules are installed into matching banks, which are usually color-coded on the motherboard. These separate channels allow the memory controller access to each memory module.

Hence, you need to use at least two memory modules for your motherboard to work. I don't know if your motherboard can work with any "two or more" memory modules configuration or if it needs a "multiple of two" memory modules configuration (that is, in your case, exactly two or four DIMMs). The user's manual for the motherboard should tell you which memory configurations are supported.

Or you can **just install both DIMMs** in a slot pair and call it a day.

Comment: Do you mean that this motherboard doesn't support fallback to single channel? I don't think this is the case.

Comment: @OleksiiTaran I don't know, but Gigabyte's web site and your experience would seem to support the conclusion that the motherboard cannot work with only a single DIMM installed. I have, however, not dug deeply into the manual and specs of your particular hardware.